# After browser screen is minimised menu bar toggler is not working in Angular. I am using bootstrap functionalities in Angular

Tags: angular, html, bootstrap-4

HTML is perfectly working for full-screen browser mode. When I am resizing the browser to a smaller size the navbar is disappearing ad toggle is shown, up to this is expected behavior. Now if I am clicking on toggle then menu list should be shown as per screen size. Following is the HTML code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-bar" 
  aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" 
  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">&#9776;</span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-bar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#social">CONNECT</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#who">WHO</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#work">WORK</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#why">WHY</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#customers">CUSTOMERS</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">PRICING</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using bootstrap css in your angular project, one solution might be to install ngx-bootstrap from :

```
 npm i ngx-bootstrap --save
```

In your app.module import the collapse module :

```
 CollapseModule.forRoot()
```

Then in your component (I imagine you have a navbarComponent.ts or similar ?)

```
  isCollapsed: boolean = false;
```

And finally in the template of the navbarComponent

```
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" (click)="isCollapsed=!isCollapsed">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"  [collapse]="isCollapsed">
   ... 
 </div>
```

Hope this helps!